# Remove duplicate words from a string without converting it into array

Tags: javascript, string

from the below code I'm trying to get common words(from two strings given) without converting the strings into array. The below code is getting and displaying the common words but the problem is, this code is not removing all the duplicates as it shows all the common words without removing duplicates. I tried searching, but the solution is to use split() and filter(). Is there any other way to remove duplicates.

Thanks so much in advance.

```js
function common() {
  var str1 = "is hello and he is the only hello is"
  var str2 = "is hello you and is and he and is the only";
  var min = 0;
  var max = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var count1 = 0;
  var count2 = 0;
  var out = '';
  var out2 = '';
  var out3 = '';
  var len1 = str1.length;
  var len2 = str2.length;
  var output = '';
  var temp = 0;
  var temp1 = 0;
  for (m = 0; m < str1.length; m++) {
    temp1 = 0;
    if (str1.charAt(m) == " " || m == str1.length - 1) {
      count1++;
      if (m == str1.length - 1) {
        out1 = str1.slice(temp, m + 1);
      } else {
        out1 = str1.slice(temp, m);
      }
      for (i = temp1; i < str2.length; i++) {
        if (str2.charAt(i) == " " || i == str2.length - 1) {
          if (i == str2.length - 1) {
            out2 = str2.slice(temp1, i + 1);
          } else {
            out2 = str2.slice(temp1, i);
          }
          temp1 = i + 1;
          if (out1 == out2) {
            if (out3.indexOf(out1) == -1) {
              out3 += out1 + ' ';
            } else if (out3.indexOf(out1) >= 0) {
              var r = out3.indexOf(out1);
              while (out3.charAt(r) != " ") {
                r++;
              }
              if (r != out1.length) {
                out3 += out1 + ' ';
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      temp = m + 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(out3);
  out = document.getElementById("tarea3");
  out.value = out3;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="tarea2"></textarea>
<textarea id="tarea3"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="common()">Run</button>
```

Comment: If there's a restriction, it might be useful to explain why that restriction exists.

Comment: *filter* is an array method, so how will you use it without turning the string into an Array or array–like object?

Comment: the execution time of string will be less than array, so I prefer string without converting it into array.

Answer (score 0):

No arrays no regex you can get the common words like this. The rest is up to your processing.

```js
var str1 = "is hello and he is the only hello is",
    str2 = "is hello you and is and he and is the only",
     lut = {},
     stc = "",
       i = 0;

while (i <= str1.length) {
  if (str1[i] !== " " && i < str1.length) {
   stc+=str1[i++];
  }  else {
   lut[stc] = "unmatch";
   stc = "";
   ++i;
  }
}

  i = 0;
stc = "";
while (i <= str2.length) {
  if (str2[i] !== " " && i < str2.length) {
   stc+=str2[i++];
  }  else {
   lut[stc] = lut[stc] ? "common" : "unmatch";
   stc = "";
   ++i;
  }
}
console.log(lut);
```